# Meteor/MongoDB see available fields for publish?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, youtube, meteor

How can I see what fields are in the users collection that are available for me to publish from the server and subscribe to from the client?  I'm using Meteor.JS's Google Auth functions, but I'm using them to authorize YouTube so the fields aren't standard or documented.

Login code:

```
Meteor.loginWithGoogle({
    requestPermissions: ['profile', 'email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube']
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inspect records in `Meteor.users` on the server, for instance by logging them to the console. For example, in server.js:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {

  Meteor.publish("nothing", function() { 
    if (this.userId)
      console.log(Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId}));
  });

});
```

Then subscribe to this in the client:

```
Meteor.subscribe("nothing");
```

This will log the contents of the logged in user to the server console (terminal window). The reason it's in a publish method is that Meteor doesn't allow accessing the current user outside a method, so I named it "nothing" to indicate that it doesn't do anything and is just for temporary inspection purposes.

Comment: What's the best way to do this?  Sorry, relative newbie with JS here :)

Comment: I tried that above and it didn't print anything to the console.

`$ meteor
[[[[[ ~/Meteor/exonia ]]]]]

Running on: http://localhost:3000/`

Comment: Oops, sorry, forgot to tell you to subscribe. Also, remove `.fetch()`. Happy new year!

Comment: Happy new year to you too!  Works perfectly :)