# How to get Google+ profile with Meteor.loginWithGoogle?

Tags: meteor, google-oauth

I'm looking for a working example of Meteor.loginWithGoogle (with meteor 0.6.4.1).

I found this one for loginWithGitHub (https://www.eventedmind.com/posts/meteor-customizing-login) that works fine with GitHub.

It works fine without parameters as show here on client side :

```
Template.user_loggedout.events({
  "click #login": function(e, tmpl){
    Meteor.loginWithGoogle({

    }, function (err) {
        if(err) {
            //error handling
            alert('error : '+err.message);
        } else {

        }
    });
  }
});
```

with the Accounts params on server side :

```
Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.remove({
   service: 'google'
});

Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.insert({
   service: 'google',
   clientId: 'XXXXXX',
   secret: 'YYYYYY'
});
```

In this case how can i get currentUser information especially the mail ?
Is there a way to get the Google+ profile of the user (if he has one and allows this), the user's avatar for example ?
What are the needed parameters for requestPermissions: , what can i get with this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

After some research i build my own example available here : https://github.com/lc3t35/googlelogin

Thanks to :

https://github.com/m2web/githublogin

https://github.com/ananta-IO/marq

[Meteor/MongoDB see available fields for publish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104391/meteor-mongodb-see-available-fields-for-publish)

https://github.com/mrtnbroder/meteor-snippets/blob/master/snippets/js/Accounts/loginWithGoogle.sublime-snippet

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#obtaininguserprofileinformation